# Disable mouseover until animation complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jquery caroufredsel to create a slider, and then attach mouseover event to the items so that when mouse over the item it will center the selected one. here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel-popular').carouFredSel({
        width: '100%',
        items: 5,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev-popular',
        next: '#next-popular',
        pagination: '#pager'
    });


    $('#carousel-popular img').off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function(){
        var self = this;
        $(this).attr('data-url', '<?php echo site_url('video/video_display'); ?>/'+$(this).data('vid'));
        $('#carousel-popular').trigger('slideTo', [$(this), -2]);

        $('#home-sidebar').load('<?php echo site_url('home/get_imdb');?>/'+$(this).data('vid'), function(){
            $('#carousel-popular img').removeClass('selected');
            $(self).addClass('selected');
        });
//      $('.caroufredsel_wrapper').css({
//          "background" : "url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/shadow.png) center 95% no-repeat"
//      });
    });

    $('#carousel-popular img').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            window.location = $(this).data('url');
        }
    })

    var sbHeight = $('body').height() - $('#header').height();
    $('#home-sidebar').css({
        "height": sbHeight+'px'
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#carousel-popular img').eq(0).trigger('mouseover');
    }, 500);
});
```

The problem is when an item is sliding to center another images catch the mouseover because the mouse pointer is still on the track. How to disable this mouseover event untill the selected image is centered?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8W25g/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the issue, but you could try this:

```
$('#carousel a').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', [$(this), -2]);
});
```

That triggers the animation when the mouse moves over the element

Answer (score 0):

pretty unclear question to me, is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/8W25g/2/

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        items: 4,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev-popular',
        next: '#next-popular',
        pagination: '#pager'
    });
var mouseoverFunc=function(){
        $('#carousel a').unbind('mouseover');
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', [$(this), -2]);
    };
var mouseoutFunc=function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#carousel a').bind('mouseover',mouseoverFunc);    
        },400);
    };
$('#carousel a').bind('mouseover', mouseoverFunc);
$('#carousel a').bind('mouseout', mouseoutFunc);
```

Comment: OP wants the `mouseover` not be triggered AGAIN while the link is not on center yet.

Comment: that is in fact what the answer does

Comment: actually no, try to mouse over to the left most side..ie. you hovered on text1 in the end text5 will be centered not text1

Comment: that's what the OP has in their question, to move to a place that is two positions to right! `$('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', [$(this), -2]);` that's not my code!

Comment: then try changing it to -1. then hovered to the right most side. still the same. i think that is the problem of the OP

Comment: can't see what you're talking about. works as it should. `[$(this), -2]` is the place which the anchor is supposed to slide to when hovered, and it does get hovered to that position.